# Bugs with button+tooltip "pull-effect"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I move cursor on a camera, button is pulling. Why? Can I solve this problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/uDj9p/

```
<div class="input-group-btn advanced-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Отправить картинку">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
    </button><button class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
.btn {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uDj9p/15/

Sometimes there is a little flicker but not sure what's causing that yet.